# Laravel 5.7 not returning new record when global scope applied

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but I am completely at a loss so any input would be greatly appreciated.

I have two models, User and Account with a many to many relationship with the model Channel.  Accounts can be associated with multiple channels and users can also be associated with multiple channels.  This has been created so that users can only access accounts that are associated with channels they are also associated with.

In order to do the filtering, I have applied a global scope to the account model so when I perform a query, it only returns accounts associated with the channels that the user is associated with.  This works as intended for everything except newly created accounts.

If I call $account = Account::find($id) on a newly created account it returns null.  If I drop the global scope it returns the account.

The only way I have found to fix the problem is if I sync the pivot table for the channel_user table and only include a single channel that is also associated with the account.

It feels like something is being cached somewhere but I'm not sure where to go from here.  Please let me know what else you need to know

Account Model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new ChannelScope);
}

public function channels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Channel');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User Model:

```
public function accounts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Account');
}

public function channels(){
    return $this->belongsToMany( 'App\Channel' );
}
```

Channel Model:

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account');
}

public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Channel Scope:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{   
    $channels_ob = Auth::user()->channels;

        $channels = array();

        foreach ($channels_ob as $channel){
            array_push($channels,$channel->id);
    }

    $builder->whereHas('channels', function ($q) use ($channels){
                $q->where('channels.id','=', $channels);});

}
```

AccountController.php Store:

```
$account->save();


    if (isset($request->chk_channels)){
        foreach($request->chk_channels as $channel){
            $ch = Channel::where('name',$channel)->get();
            $ch_array[] = $ch[0]->id;
        }

    }

    $account->channels()->sync($ch_array);
```

UserController.php update_channels:

```
public function update_channels(Request $request, $id)
{   
    $user = User::find($id);

    if ($user->hasPermission('view_all_accounts')){
        if (isset($request->chk_channels)){

        foreach($request->chk_channels as $channel){
            $ch = Channel::where('name',$channel)->get();
            $ch_array[] = $ch[0]->id;
        }

        $user->channels()->sync($ch_array);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a column value equivalent to an array.  You're building up an array of channels in your scope and then checking equivalency:

```
$q->where('channels.id','=', $channels);
```

Perhaps, you want whereIn:

```
$q->whereIn('channels.id', $channels);
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing something small!